# React-Native, Redux, useSelector generating error "Invalid hook call"

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

Based on help received on an earlier post, I am now using React-Native functional components and the newer Redux hooks for getting and setting global Redux state variables.

My problem arose when trying to create an external function (file "authentication.js") that is trying to GET the value of a stored variable "username" using the "useSelector" Redux function.

It works great from the external file "DetailsScreen.js" but fails in the other external file "authentication.js", even though to my untrained eyes looks like the same code, with some obviously slight differences.

**This code works perfectly:**

*DetailsScreen.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import type { Node } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

export const DetailsScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const syncedDate = useSelector(state => state.projects.syncedDate);
  console.log('DetailsScreen syncedDate: ', syncedDate);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const changeDate = newDate => dispatch({type: "PJS_SET_SYNCEDDATE", payload: newDate});

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details</Text>
      <Text>SyncedDate: {syncedDate}</Text>
      <Button
        title="SetDate"
        onPress={() => changeDate("10/15/2021")}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default DetailsScreen;
```

**But this code generates an error: "Invalid hook call"**

*authentication.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import type { Node } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export const authStage_getToken = () => {
    const username = useSelector(state => state.authentication.username);
    const password = 'testingEncoding';

    // Encode the String
    const credentials = base64.encode(username + ':' + password);
    console.log('authStage_getToken encoded credentials:', credentials);

    return credentials;
}

export default authStage_getToken;
```

**Other file that launches this function:**

*LoginScreen.js*

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import type { Node } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View, Button, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { authStage_getToken } from '../processes/authentication';

export const LoginScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState(useSelector(state => state.authentication.username));

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const changeLogin = newLogin => dispatch({type: "AUTH_SET_LOGINAUTHENTICATION", payload: newLogin});

  const onButtonPress = () => {
    if (!username || username === '') {
      setValidationError("Username cannot be blank.");
    } else {
      changeLogin({username:username,password:password});
    }

    console.log('Before triggering getToken...');
    const result = authStage_getToken();
    console.log('After triggering getToken, result: ', result);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>   
      <View style={styles.inputRow}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Username"
          placeholderTextColor="#808080"
          autoFocus={true}
          onChangeText={(text) => setUsername(text)}
          value={username}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputRow}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => onButtonPress()}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default LoginScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
  container: {
...
```

Comment: probably component not correctly called, console.log result is not good

Answer (score 0):

You are using authStage_getToken function as an ordinary Javascript function, but it's actually a custom hook because of the useSelector, so you need to treat it like one on LoginScreen.
If you move const result = authStage_getToken() under your userName hook you should be good to go.
You'll find more information about custom hooks here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

Comment: Redux is supposed to allow me to access global state from anywhere, right?
I'm trying to access a Redux state variable's value from the external file "authentication".
How do I do that?
The above code is me attempting to do just that, and I get an error.
Note: the reason I am trying to call the "authStage_getToken() at that particular spot is because after the username value is validated in the "buttonPressed" function, I need to proceed with the process flow, beginning with an external call to an API, hence the getToken name.